# set background color generically to elements

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have two Text views in my xml file.

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Trainings"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:onClick="changeColor"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/learning_programs"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Learning Programs"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="changeColor"/>
```

By default the background color of both of these is grey as set by the drawable rounded_corner.xml file, and when any of these is clicked I want it to change to white.
In my Java file I have

```
public void changeColor(){
    this.setBackground(getResources().getColor((R.color.dark_grey_color)));
}
```

I know that I can use setOnclickListener and run a switch-case between the ids of the buttons based on View.

But the requirement is to it this way.
So, how can I implement it this way?

Thanks.

Comment: *how can I implement it this way?* What way man?

Comment: by giving some code in changeColor() in a generic manner for TextViews @Vucko

Comment: but when you change background your rounded corner xml will replaced with simple color. So are you want grey text color with rounded background?? @Aayushi

Comment: I have grey rounded background in normal state. When any of the textViews is clicked, the rounded_corner_grey should override the previous one? @Vucko

Comment: Do you want the text views to maintain the replaced color after being clicked or do you want to toggle the color when clicking?

Comment: I have updated my answer you can check it. @Aayushi

Comment: what exactly you want? will the color change permanently after clicking once?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below code snipet onclick of your textview

```
your_textview.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.white));
```

Comment: I want to set the background. Sorry I will update the question. Please check @yash786

Comment: @Aayushi Sorry for wrong editing just check the above edited answer it will definitely work in all api level without any issue.

Comment: I think he wants to change background color not text color.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your function. Replace `Color.BLUE` with whatever color or drawable you want. Because when you set onClick from xml it passes its view to the activity which you can get using view,getId to identify which click performed. In your case you are passing textview so cast that to textview.

```
 public void changeColor(View view) {
            //((TextView) view).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

           GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)((TextView) view).getBackground();
           bgShape.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the view to **maintain its background** once it is clicked then you can keep the **TextView** and simply change the background color on the *changeColor* method. If you want it to **toggle** the background color according to click then it's a **checkbox** behaviour. If you want this last behaviour then implement it as follows:

**Checkbox**:

```
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Trainings"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/view_state"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/learning_programs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Learning Programs"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/view_state"
            android:gravity="center"/>
```

Then add a drawable to define those states (**drawable/view_state**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000" /> <!-- clicked color -->
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF" /> <!-- default color -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```